# Repeated Kernel Panic on 5K iMac

Tags: imac, crash, kernel-panic

Anyone have any ideas what cause my iMac to crash?

Here are some panic reports...

```
Anonymous UUID:       80AC7863-37B8-41EC-B86D-74843925A2FD

Fri Jan 23 11:45:47 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801541e80a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801575a806, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000000004a000030, CR3: 0x0000000016813001, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x000000004a000000, RBX: 0xffffff804f7d0780, RCX: 0x0000000025000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff8205c13d00, RBP: 0xffffff8205c13d20, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0xffffff804f7c70a8
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000002000, R11: 0x0000000000000004
R12: 0xffffff804f7d0780, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff8205c13e18, R15: 0xffffff804f7c70a8
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff801575a806, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x000000004a000030, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x3

mp = 0xffffff803794bc00, phys = 0x174fcc00, prev (0x7: 0x15113000-0x15200000)
vp = 0xffffff803794bc00, phys = 0x331294780, prev (0xb: 0xffe10000-0xffe40000)
0xffffff803794a000: 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
0xffffff803794b000: fgAAAIcAAACRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAgB4fCQcgAACACAAAACETGg6Gk6LTgoMaP0QBMwACKQQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwMAeH4mHLgAGwAgAAAAhExoNqeMiE4qPKr9oAuoAAhoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAinQzeA////AAACAP8PAAAAAAAh/////z8AAAAADWg5gP///9BSfzrulncEAKiUNwC8lDcwCaYVINylFYD///+w5KE3UGqZR+DjoTdQspQ3ABAQBAAQEADoBBU3ZGV2Zi9kZXYAAAIA/w8AAACgQaz/////9RwAACtABQAAAAAhPwAAAMDwmTfA46E3B7hNBSBTrxVL/gMAAAAwAP////8Y3qYVYNulFWDJG0WgB31PcAh9T3DqoTdgvJQ3ANCABAAA3YAQAAAAABAAAAAAEACgwTcQO9NfCzvZXgtl6NgECAAAAREAAABoZnMAzAAADA7u7gDu7r7uAAAAMAAHzsxw4ODlvu7g4O7unj4AAAAAIAAIAgFs3gACBPU/gIMJIHcpOgFzgAAgIASQCZsD3gACAAg4nr0AAAAA
0xffffff803794c000: 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
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8205c139b0 : 0xffffff801533a811 
0xffffff8205c13a30 : 0xffffff801541e80a 
0xffffff8205c13bf0 : 0xffffff801543a443 
0xffffff8205c13c10 : 0xffffff801575a806 
0xffffff8205c13d20 : 0xffffff8015542c3b 
0xffffff8205c13dd0 : 0xffffff8015757da7 
0xffffff8205c13eb0 : 0xffffff801555c86b 
0xffffff8205c13ed0 : 0xffffff8015546ef4 
0xffffff8205c13f40 : 0xffffff80155510f7 
0xffffff8205c13f50 : 0xffffff801584dcb2 
0xffffff8205c13fb0 : 0xffffff801543ac46 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: launchd

Mac OS version:
14B25

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x0000000015000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8015200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8015100000
System model name: iMac15,1 (Mac-42FD25EABCABB274)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 7443308919007
last loaded kext at 2464177111540: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs  11.0 (addr 0xffffff7f98558000, size 364544)
last unloaded kext at 160176647500: com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9775c000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.1f2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000    1.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.1f2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   901.19.10
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  175.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   175.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  260.30
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 267.0
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.2.8
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: iMac15,1, BootROM IM151.0207.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 3.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.22f16
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M290X, AMD Radeon R9 M290X, PCIe, 2048 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x014F, 0x54533147534B363457364820202020202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x142), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.10)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST1000DM003, 1 TB
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Composite Device
USB Device: Fitbit Base Station
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 26.1
```

```
Anonymous UUID:       80AC7863-37B8-41EC-B86D-74843925A2FD

Thu Jan 29 17:46:56 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff802001a46e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff802012d8bf, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff820042a078, CR3: 0x0000000023913000, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0xffffff80206c1bc0, RBX: 0xffffff820342a140, RCX: 0xffffff820042a050, RDX: 0xffffff820342a168
RSP: 0xffffff820f79b900, RBP: 0xffffff820f79b920, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff820342a140
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000010, R10: 0x0000000000000001, R11: 0xffffff81c17fe000
R12: 0x00000000deadbeef, R13: 0xffffff820342a140, R14: 0x0000000000000003, R15: 0xffffff820b687008
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff802012d8bf, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffff820042a078, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff820f79b5b0 : 0xffffff801ff2fe41 
0xffffff820f79b630 : 0xffffff802001a46e 
0xffffff820f79b7f0 : 0xffffff8020036683 
0xffffff820f79b810 : 0xffffff802012d8bf 
0xffffff820f79b920 : 0xffffff802012c5c9 
0xffffff820f79b960 : 0xffffff802012db6a 
0xffffff820f79b9c0 : 0xffffff802012bc93 
0xffffff820f79baa0 : 0xffffff802012d610 
0xffffff820f79bb00 : 0xffffff802012b2b7 
0xffffff820f79bb20 : 0xffffff7fa19c3656 
0xffffff820f79bc20 : 0xffffff7fa19c3a74 
0xffffff820f79bc50 : 0xffffff7fa1a36b7b 
0xffffff820f79bd30 : 0xffffff7fa1a36f72 
0xffffff820f79bde0 : 0xffffff7fa1a36fb0 
0xffffff820f79be90 : 0xffffff7fa1a2e02f 
0xffffff820f79bef0 : 0xffffff7fa1a2de79 
0xffffff820f79bf80 : 0xffffff7fa1a28537 
0xffffff820f79bfb0 : 0xffffff8020014dd7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.CoreStorage(471.10.6)[AE6240EF-D194-3791-BAF0-59CF6B5CF4D2]@0xffffff7fa19a5000->0xffffff7fa1a82fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.0)[76E50D45-C97B-3ED1-97C5-94E6E0EB4514]@0xffffff7fa0647000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
Not yet set

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DCF5C2D5-16AE-37F5-B2BE-ED127048DFF5
Kernel slide:     0x000000001fc00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801fe00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801fd00000
System model name: iMac15,1 (Mac-42FD25EABCABB274)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2165800452
last loaded kext at 1704318484: com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471.10.6 (addr 0xffffff7fa1a89000, size 106496)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   910.26.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: iMac15,1, BootROM IM151.0207.B01, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 3.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.22f16
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M290X, AMD Radeon R9 M290X, PCIe, 2048 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x014F, 0x54533147534B363457364820202020202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x142), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.159.13.12)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST1000DM003, 1 TB
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Fitbit Base Station
USB Device: Composite Device
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 26.1
```

```
Anonymous UUID:       80AC7863-37B8-41EC-B86D-74843925A2FD

Sat Jan 31 17:57:36 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801461a46e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9722d0f5, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00006000018c6000, CR3: 0x0000000017f13000, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0xffffff7f5b626230, RBX: 0xffffff7f97625f38, RCX: 0xffffff7f97392720, RDX: 0xffffff8014a5cf40
RSP: 0xffffff81d653cdd4, RBP: 0xd653ce20ffffff7f, RSI: 0xffffff7f97625f38, RDI: 0xffffff803873a700
R8:  0xffffff81d653ce00, R9:  0xffffff81d653ced0, R10: 0x8a51eb67b63b0049, R11: 0x0000121a9cd7ea01
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff8200433e50, R14: 0xffffff803873a700, R15: 0xffffff81b5c2e000
RFL: 0x0000000000010087, RIP: 0xffffff7f9722d0f5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00006000018c6000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81d6548c70 : 0xffffff801452fe41 
0xffffff81d6548cf0 : 0xffffff801461a46e 
0xffffff81d6548eb0 : 0xffffff8014636683 
0xffffff81d6548ed0 : 0xffffff7f9722d0f5 
Unaligned frame
Backtrace terminated-invalid frame pointer 0xd653ce20ffffff7f
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller(1.3)[7FB352CB-B00D-3C69-A78B-37D58851EE5E]@0xffffff7f97207000->0xffffff7f97626fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f95555000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f94d24000
            dependency: com.apple.kext.AMDSupport(1.3.0)[F69B43AA-4529-3560-8643-66579222A749]@0xffffff7f96a68000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f95618000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14C109

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DCF5C2D5-16AE-37F5-B2BE-ED127048DFF5
Kernel slide:     0x0000000014200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8014400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8014300000
System model name: iMac15,1 (Mac-42FD25EABCABB274)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 19905512520670
last loaded kext at 14320821419935: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7f977e8000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 14463112732396: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7f977e8000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.7d1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000    1.3.0
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.3.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   910.26.12
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  262.33.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: iMac15,1, BootROM IM151.0207.B01, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 3.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.22f16
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M290X, AMD Radeon R9 M290X, PCIe, 2048 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x014F, 0x54533147534B363457364820202020202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x142), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.159.13.12)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST1000DM003, 1 TB
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Fitbit Base Station
USB Device: Composite Device
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 26.1
```

---

I do have a USB scanner, a USB numeric pad, and a Fitbit dongle connected to my iMac. I have been using these things for a long time without any problem though.

Also, I run Rember to check my RAM and it passed the test.

I used the Disk Utility to verify and repair both disk permission and the disk volume and everything seemed fine.

I used Apple Diagnostic Tool (Control D when restart the machine) and it did not find anything wrong.

Finally, I already reinstalled Yosemite but the panic kernel still showed up.

Comment: Do you have any external storage devices connected over USB?

Comment: Try to plug out all your external devices and then boot.

Comment: happens on my new 5k iMac about twice per day